# Not able to integrate lambda function with api gateway using terraform

Tags: terraform, integration, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I am dealing with terraform api gateway integration challenge and I am not understanding what happens. I followed totorial to create lambda function and upload it correctly to S3.
Next, I created this file to create API gateway and integrate the lambda function

here is my code

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "example" {
  name        = "ServerlessExample"
  description = "Terraform Serverless Application Example"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "MyDemoResource" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id}"
  parent_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.root_resource_id}"
  path_part   = "item"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "MyDemoMethod" {
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource.id}"
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

 resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "integration" {
  rest_api_id             = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id}"
  resource_id             = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.MyDemoResource.id}"
  http_method             = "${aws_api_gateway_method.MyDemoMethod.http_method}"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = "${aws_lambda_function.example.invoke_arn}$"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "example" {
   depends_on = [
     aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda_root
   ]

   rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
   stage_name  = "dev"
 }


output "base_url" {
  value = aws_api_gateway_deployment.example.invoke_url
}
```

When doing terraform apply, I get this error

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on api_gateway.tf line 30, in resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "example":
  30:      aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda_root

A managed resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda_root" has not been
declared in the root module.
```

Comment: Do you have a resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda_root" { ... }? I can only see *aws_api_gateway_integration.integration*

Comment: I this I was really tired whan I posted this. That was nit the erreor I want t post.